# Explicit bounds for the asymptotics of oscillatory integrals

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, real-analysis

Recall the following theorem (c.f. [LC Evans, M Zworski, "Lectures on semiclassical analysis"](http://math.berkeley.edu/~zworski/semiclassical.pdf), Theorem 3.15, depending on the version):

**Theorem:**  Let $\varphi: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be smooth and $a: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ smooth with compact support $K$.  Suppose that there exists $x_0 \in K$ with $\partial \varphi(x_0) = 0$ and $\det \partial^2 \varphi(x_0) \neq 0$, and suppose that $\partial \varphi \neq 0$ on $K\smallsetminus \{ x_0\}$.
  For positive $\hbar$, define:
$$ I_\hbar = \int_{\mathbb R^n} e^{i\varphi(x)/\hbar} \, a(x)\,dx $$
Then for $k=0,1,\dots$, there exists differential operators $A_{2k}(x,\partial)$ of order $\leq 2k$, and constants $C_N$, all depending on $\varphi$, such that for each $N$ we have:
$$ \left| I_\hbar - \hbar^{n/2} \,e^{i\varphi(x_0)/\hbar} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} A_{2k}(x,\partial) \, a(x_0)\,\hbar^k\right| \leq C_N\, \hbar^{N + \frac n 2} \sum_{|\alpha| \leq 2N + n+1} \sup_K | \partial^\alpha a|$$
where $\partial^\alpha$ is shorthand for some product of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$s.

**My question:** I know how to give the operators $A_{2k}$ explicitly; they depend only on the Taylor expansion of $\varphi$ at $x_0$, and are succinctly described combinatorially by ``Feynman diagrams''.  What I would like to know is how explicitly the $C_N$ can be given?  For example, can $C_N$ be taken to depend on the maximum values of some finite list (depending on $N$, of course) of derivatives of $\varphi$?

The reason I'm asking is that the above theorem gives $I_\hbar$ to an accuracy of $O(\hbar^\infty)$, but I would like to vary $\varphi$ and study $I_\hbar$ in some limit, and to know that my $O(\hbar^\infty)$ estimates still hold, I need to swap some limits, which requires more explicit description of the estimates.

As with any post, feel free to re-tag as appropriate.

Comment: Theorem 3.15, FYI

Comment: Google (or Amazon) won't let me look at it (even after trying to be a little clever), but whatever reference 20 is in http://books.google.com/books?id=CEwulgtYT6EC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_v2_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=&f=false
might have some info. Also you might find something in volume 1 of Hormander's linear PDE book (which I also don't have).

Comment: I am now 99% sure this reference 20 is http://www.iop.org/EJ/abstract/-search=68666845.91/0036-0279/26/1/R02

Comment: Huh.  So I have "version 0.3", in which it is Theorem 3.14, whereas the link (which is what is currently linked from Zworski's website) is to "version 0.2".  I've changed the number.

Comment: If you're OK with Russian, see 2.22 in http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=5166&option_lang=eng

Comment: The key estimate (in one dimension) appears to be 2.17.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't realize this had such connections with physics... Anyhow, 
I didn't work out every detail but 
I think this works: First note that one can write $a(x) = a(x)\psi_1(x)
+ a(x)\psi_2(x)$ where $\psi_1$ is 1 on a neighborhood of x_0 to be described
in a moment, and where the second term does not affect the asymptotics
due to the nonvanishing gradient condition.

Next, note by Morse's lemma if $\psi_1$ was chosen correctly, one can change 
coordinates on the support of $a(x)\psi_1(x)$ to make the 
phase just $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2$. The key is that the coordinate change can be given 
by the composition of a finite set of quite explicit coordinate changes
(see p.347 of Stein's Harmonic Analysis for example). You'll get a Jacobian
factor and $a(x)\psi_1(x)$ gets replaced by its composition
with the coordinate change. Since the phase function is now
fixed, the standard asymptotic methods will give $C_N$ in terms of finitely many 
derivatives of the components of the coordinate change as well as the cutoff $\psi_1$

So the question becomes how to describe the derivatives of the components of the coordinate change. This
is where you should check the details carefully, but what I believe is 
that if you use the formulas on p.347 or something similar, using minors to
explicitly write the inverse function, in addition to suprema of finitely many derivatives
of $\phi(x)$ you will get an additional factor
of a negative power of the smallest eigenvalue of the Hessian, if the 
support of $\psi_1$ is small enough. So ultimately, your constants should
be a constant times a product of a) the suprema of finitely many derivatives of $\phi(x)$, b) a negative power of the smallest eigenvalue of the Hessian, and c) a function of the size of the support of $\psi_1$.

You can't get rid of b)... consider the case where your phase is just a quadratic polynomial. I can't see offhand if there's a better way to
deal with the cutoff (or if you care about it anyhow).

Answer (score 2):

Back in the mid 80's, Jonathan Goodman and I studied a similar question. We needed smooth tame estimates for a Fourier integral operator, so we could solve nonlinear PDE's of nonlinear principal type. Specifically, we wanted to prove a local isometric embedding of a 4-dimensional Riemannian manifold.

To do this, we needed a finite version, including an explicit error term, of the asymptotic expansion found by Hormander of the parametrix (which is a Fourier integral operator) of a differential operator of real principal type.

Unfortunately, we never published the paper and by now neither Jonathan nor I have a complete copy of the paper. It was written using a now-obselete Mac word processor (the irony is that I was one of the first people to type up a Ph.D. thesis in TeX but I then abandoned it for Mac GUI word processors before returning to LaTeX). If anybody has a copy lying around somewhere, I'd be very grateful if you could send me a copy.

Anyway, I can still offer some rather vague advice on this. I suggest trying to work through the proof of the asymptotic expansion but using a finite Taylor expansion and the explicit integral error formula for the Taylor polynomial. It is especially instructive to work out first the 1-term Taylor expansion with explicit error term, i.e. the fundamental theorem of calculus. I don't know if this is at all useful (since I do not know the theorem you refer to), but it worked beautifully for Jonathan and me.

Comment: I've noticed that you finally found a full copy of your paper with Prof. Goodman, as indicated in your web page... Sweet!

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of digging, I traced the exposition of your Theorem 3.14/15 first to Fedoryuk, then to Erdelyi. However Erdelyi's treatment of the problem is different than what you need:

> The main purpose of the present paper is to supply explicit expressions for 
>   the error terms associated with the expansions of [4] from which realistic bounds 
>   are readily computable. The derivations of Erdelyi do not lend themselves readily 
>   to the construction of error bounds owing to the somewhat artificial nature of the 
>   neutralizer functions employed in the analysis. Our approach is based instead on 
>   Hardy’s theory of generalized integrals [7], [8].

This is from a paper of Olver available [here](http://scitation.aip.org/getabs/servlet/GetabsServlet?prog=normal&id=SJMAAH000005000001000019000001). While it deals only with the one-dimensional case, I would expect that to give you a decent starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The following article by [Jorge Rezende](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-101/issue-2/The-method-of-stationary-phase-for-oscillatory-integrals-on-Hilbert/cmp/1104114122.full), treats a general case of the method of stationary phase on a Hilbert space. An estimate of the "remainder" term of the asymptotic series is given in which the dependence on N is explicit. The expression assumes absolute convergence of the moments of the Fourier transform of a(x) and the nonquadratic part of phi(x).